# Speeding Up Access 2016 Query

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access

I have a query that contains amongst other things batsmanIDs and League names (extract below). I have put together another query to return all records where a batsman has played in each of two Leagues.

The query works but it is very, very slow.

There are 48,000 records returned in the first query but when I use that it runs instantly.

Can anyone suggest how to speed the new query up?

Thanks

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM AddDateLeagueSeasontoScorecardBatting
WHERE League ="Indian Premier League" AND batsmanId IN (SELECT batsmanId FROM AddDateLeagueSeasontoScorecardBatting WHERE League ="Big Bash League") OR League ="Big Bash League" AND batsmanId IN (SELECT batsmanId FROM AddDateLeagueSeasontoScorecardBatting WHERE League ="Indian Premier League");
```

Table:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this using `inner joins` such that the query will return only those records with a batmans appearing in both subqueries:

```
select t1.* from 
(
    AddDateLeagueSeasontoScorecardBatting t1 inner join
    (
        select distinct batsmanid 
        from AddDateLeagueSeasontoScorecardBatting 
        where League ="Indian Premier League"
    ) t2 on t1.batsmanid = t2.batsmanid
) 
inner join
(
    select distinct batsmanid 
    from AddDateLeagueSeasontoScorecardBatting 
    where League ="Big Bash League"
) t3 on t1.batsmanid = t3.batsmanid
```

**EDIT:** To select batsmen who have *only* played in the two leagues in question (and no others), you might try:

```
select t1.* from 
AddDateLeagueSeasontoScorecardBatting t1 inner join
(
    select batsmanid
    from AddDateLeagueSeasontoScorecardBatting 
    group by batsmanid
    having 
        sum(League not in ("Indian Premier League", "Big Bash League")) = 0 and
        sum(League = "Indian Premier League") < 0 and 
        sum(League = "Big Bash League") < 0
) t2 on t1.batsmanid = t2.batsmanid
```

Comment: Thanks Lee, this looks good however it returns records for other leagues in addition to the IPL and BBL.

Comment: @rob Are you only interested in batsmen who have *only* played in IPL and BBL, as opposed to batsmen who have played in these two amongst others?

Comment: Hi Lee, yes exactly that. Thanks

Comment: @rob Could you please try the SQL in my edit above?

Comment: Hi Lee, thanks for this. I've tested it and it shows batsmen who have played in either the IPL or the BBL, not the IPL and the BBL.

Comment: @rob Apologies - I've revised it again.

Answer (score 1):

So, you are interested to get batsman who played in both leagues. There is a design problem in your database. Think about your query: you are searching by string values, which is very slow, particularly in the case when there are other possible values for those strings, which are very similar to the one you are searching for. You would need to create a table for leagues, where you would store the name of the league, possibly along with other attributes and a numeric id.

Create a `foreign key` in your `AddDateLeagueSeasontoScorecardBatting` referring to the id of the newly created other table for leagues. Index your foreign key, so searches will dramatically quicken up. You should know that you will have a price to pay in performance when records are inserted or the indexed key changes at an update. Now that you have a league table and an indexed foreign key referring to it, try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM AddDateLeagueSeasontoScorecardBatting MAIN
JOIN League IPL
on IPL.Name = 'Indian Premier League'
JOIN League BBL
on BBL.Name = 'Big Bash League'
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM AddDateLeagueSeasontoScorecardBatting FIRST
    JOIN AddDateLeagueSeasontoScorecardBatting SECOND
    ON FIRST.batsmanId = SECOND.batsmanId AND
       FIRST.batsmanId = MAIN.batsmanId AND
       FIRST.LeagueId = IPL.LeagueId AND
       SECOND.LeagueId = BBL.LeagueId
);
```

Note: You will probably want to use the `distinct` keyword or to `group by`, but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this where clause:

```sql
WHERE batsmanId IN 
    (SELECT batsmanId
    FROM AddDateLeagueSeasontoScorecardBatting 
    GROUP BY batsmanId
    HAVING (League IN ("Indian Premier League","Big Bash League")) AND Count(*) = 2)
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav but each of the suggestions include results for batsman that played in just one of the two leagues, not just batsman who played in both leagues.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've edited the answer (air code only, as I have no similar data to test with).

Comment: Thanks Gustav. I get a "Cannot have aggregate function in WHERE clause" error. This is how I added it: `SELECT *
FROM AddDateLeagueSeasontoScorecardBatting
WHERE batsmanId IN 
    (SELECT batsmanId 
    FROM AddDateLeagueSeasontoScorecardBatting 
    WHERE (League IN ("Indian Premier League","Big Bash League")) AND Count(*) = 2
    GROUP BY batsmandId);`

Comment: I've done yet an edit. See corrected answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to simplify your query. Try this:

`SELECT * FROM AddDateLeagueSeasontoScorecardBatting WHERE League = "Indian Premier League"  or League = "Big Bash League"`

Comment: Thanks Nick but this too includes results for batsman that played in just one of the two leagues, not just batsman who played in both leagues.